# Manipular Conteúdo Carregado Dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso manipular um atributo de uma tag html que foi carregada dinamicamente através de ajax.
Já tentei de diversas formas usando jQuery porém nenhuma delas deu certo.

O código que está sendo carregado via ajax é o seguinte:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="idTablePhoneFC" style="max-width: 480px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="EstChkValorCampo">
        <input type="text" onchange="F$.fnCleanErrField('P2Telefone');" style="width:100px" maxlength="20" size="10" value="" id="P2Telefone" name="P2Telefone" class="InputText"><span></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note que o campo `input[type=text]` está com o atributo "style" forçando uma largura máxima de 100px.
Tentei usar CSS !important para tentar forçar o elemento à ficar com uma largura maior do que isso, porém ele não está aceitando.
Então minha ideia foi tentar usando jquery, porém não obtive resultados com o seguinte código:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#P2Telefone").css('width','100%');

    $(window).bind('load',function(){
        $("#P2Telefone").css('width','100%');
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#P2Telefone").css('width','100%');
    });

    $(window).on("load",function(){
        $("#P2Telefone").css('width','100%');
    });
});
</script>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Poderia postar como está criando esse html dinâmico? Se possível, explique também o que deseja fazer com ele.

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando exemplos de código.

Comment: tente substituir seu método .bind() pelo método .delegate() ou .on() que é mais atual.

Comment: Ok Thomas Lima, valeu pela dica.. vou tentar e posto os resultados.

Comment: Tentei usar o método .on() conforme orientou @ThomasLima porém não funcionou.
O método .delegate() não entendi muito bem como eu poderia aplicá-lo nesta situação, pois preciso que o css seja modificado dinamicamente através do jQuery assim que a página é carregada.Se alguém tiver mais alguma ideia, favor postar.

Comment: Onde você tem a função que carrega a página dinamicamente? O "$(window).load" é referente ao seu HTML atual e não a sua página que será carregada.

Comment: @robsonds a nivel de teste, tente alterar a '$(function() {...}' para '$(document).ready(function(){...})

Comment: @FilipeMoraes a função que carrega o conteúdo dinamicamente está no final do `<body>`.

Não estou certo, mas creio que seja esta a função:
`<script>
F$.ShowWaitingFull();
function fnStartChk(){
  F$.CmdExecIn(F$.CmdChkRegister,{},F$.fnChkRegister);
}
window.onload=fnStartChk;
</script>`

Comment: @ThomasLima alterei `$(function() {...}` para `$(document).ready(function(){...})` mas não surtiu efeito infelizmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao termino do carregamento da pagina, o `input#P2Telefone` ainda não está disponível, o mesmo só estará disponível apos a requisição `AJAX`.

Então você tem duas opçãos, mover o `$("#P2Telefone").css('width','100%');` para dentro da sua requisição `$.ajax`. Ou colocar no seu arquivo CSS `#P2Telefone { width: 100% !important; }`

Segue abaixo um exemplo funcionando....

```js
//criando URL que irá servir o HTML dinamico por AJAX.
var createURL = function () {
  var tmplHtml = document.getElementById("tmplHtml");
  var blobHtml = new Blob([tmplHtml.innerHTML], { type: 'text/html' });
  return URL.createObjectURL(blobHtml);  
}

var url = createURL();
var btAjax = document.getElementById("btAjax");
btAjax.addEventListener("click", function () {    
  
  //realizando requisição ajax
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("GET", url, false);
  httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = httpRequest.response;
        var conteudo = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        
        var p2Telefone = conteudo.querySelector("#P2Telefone");        
        p2Telefone.style.width = "100%";                
        document.body.appendChild(conteudo);  
      } else {
        console.erro("Erro durante a requisição AJAX");
      }
    }
  });
  httpRequest.send();
});

// esperar o carregamento da pagina
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {  
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {        
    // O input#P2Telefone não está disponivel neste ponto
    var p2Telefone = document.getElementById("#P2Telefone");
    p2Telefone.style.width = "100%";
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="btAjax" type="button" value="Adicionar Input" />
<template id="tmplHtml">
  <div>
    <input id="P2Telefone" type="text" style="width:100px" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Agradeço à todos pela ajuda. Acabei conseguindo usar `#P2Telefone { width: 100% !important; }` para forçar a largura do elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso utilize o .attr e não .css.

Ficaria assim:

```
$("#P2Telefone").attr('style','width:100%');
```

Mas como seu elemento está sendo carregado via ajax, você precisará inserir esse código dentro do final do método ajax.